# Temporary lifetime extension and implicit conversion to a const reference

Tags: c++

Normally, binding a temporary to a local `const&` extends the lifetime of the temporary until the end of the scope of the reference:

```
struct Foo { void DoSomething() const; };
Foo Make();

const Foo& foo = Make(); // compiles
foo.DoSomething(); // ok, lifetime of foo was extended
```

But when an implicit conversion is involved, this is no longer the case:

```
struct Foo { void DoSomething(); };
struct Bar { operator const Foo&() const; };
Bar Make();

const Foo& foo = Make(); // compiles calling the implicit conversion operator
foo.DoSomething(); // not ok, temporary Bar has been destroyed
```

Is this actually what is specified in the C++ standard? Is this intended? Is it legal to declare such an implicit conversion operators to a `const&`? (Another question is how that conversion operator should be implemented. In this case, it would need to involve a `reinterpret_cast` relying on `Foo` and `Bar` having a compatible binary representation, which is probably undefined behavior. In C++20, probably a `bit_cast` might be used? But suppose `Foo` derived from `Bar`, a `static_cast` could be used, removing the undefined behavior and the situation does not change).

Comment: Please stick to one question.

Comment: `void DoSomething();` -> `void DoSomething() const;`. `when an implicit conversion is involved, this is no longer the case` `not ok, temporary Bar has been destroyed` Would you be able to give some reference of that an implicit conversion shortens the lifetime of an object? Where from do you have such information? What is the lifetime of `foo` then?

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure, I need to come up with a bit more complex example that reproducibly crashes on some gcc/clang version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this intended?

Yes. The [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) of temporary `Bar` won't be extended to the lifetime of `foo`.

> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.

That means, the lifetime of temporary bound to reference directly would be extended. In this case, the temporary `Bar` returned by `Make()` isn't bound to `foo` directly.